# Is the img.src attribute necessary?

Tags: javascript, css

Is it necessary to set the `src` tag in an `img`? If i don't set this Attribute, I don't see an Image. Although I set the attribute `background-image`. How can I create an Image without the src tag?

```
function insertLinkHoverImage(datei,datei2,verlinkung) 
{
    var doc = document.getElementById("frame").contentWindow.document;

    var range = doc.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    var nnode = doc.createElement("img");
    var alink = doc.createElement("a");
    var classDatei2 = "";

    alink.href = verlinkung;
    classDatei2 = datei.replace(".","-");

                alink.setAttribute("class",classDatei2);

    //nnode.src = 'http://...../cms/uploads/'+datei;
    nnode.setAttribute("styleWithCss",true,null);
    nnode.setAttribute("style","background-image:url(http://..../cms/uploads/"+datei+")");

    alink.appendChild(nnode);
    range.insertNode(alink);

}
```

Comment: If you want to show an image as a background, just use a `<div>` or a `<span>` or something.

Comment: ok tried it with span but i didn't see an Image. i changed the createElement img to span is this right? it creates the span tag with Background-Image but i can't see an Image

Comment: you should set the height and width of it to display the image, and you want to use a block div not span - http://jsfiddle.net/pu891urr/

Comment: [Here is a fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/k5fs44y2/)

Comment: An empty span won't have any size, so there's nothing for the background to show as the background of. I have to ask, though, why do you not want to use a normal img with src?

Comment: SPAN is inline, so height and width do nothing (unless you override its display). Use DIV.

Comment: i Need it without src because i have a dynamich hover Effect. so if i have a scr in the Image, the background-Image doesn't work. i Need a solution. 1. i want to see the Image 2. and after the save i create a dynamic css hover effect

Comment: and when i use a div a get an automatic break. and i don't Need the break after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All HTML attributes have a specific use.

if you are using an image with `<img>` tag, src is an essential attribute to be specified, either initially or later programatically.

If you want to use a background image, you may need to specify the height and width properties of the container element.

Example:

```
<div style="background-image: url({image url here}; height: {height of the background image}; width: {width of the background image}"></div>
```

If you use a div, the background will be visible upto the height of the div.

You can use `width: auto;` or `width: 100%;` to occupy full width of the container element, but `height: auto;` or `height: 100%;` will not work in all cases.

Note that div is a block element. If you are using a span than you may need to set style to include `display : block;` in your case.

Comment: thank you for this wonderful tip with Display: block; now i can see the span with background-Image thx. a lot.

Comment: It is upto you how you use html elements, I would not use a span applying custom styling to apply an image unless there was no other option. I would directly use an image if I am rendering and image and if I am applying a background, I would choose an appropriate containing element i.e. div or section.

Answer (score 2):

The W3C website — http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140429/embedded-content-0.html#the-img-element — is telling us that:

> The src attribute must be present, and must contain a valid non-empty URL potentially surrounded by spaces referencing a non-interactive, optionally animated, image resource that is neither paged nor scripted.
>
> The requirements above imply that images can be static bitmaps (e.g.
>   PNGs, GIFs, JPEGs), single-page vector documents (single-page PDFs,
>   XML files with an SVG root element), animated bitmaps (APNGs, animated
>   GIFs), animated vector graphics (XML files with an SVG root element
>   that use declarative SMIL animation), and so forth. However, these
>   definitions preclude SVG files with script, multipage PDF files,
>   interactive MNG files, HTML documents, plain text documents, and so
>   forth.

If you want to have your code validated, don't forget the `alt` attribute, too.